# How to fix error: constructor Server in class Server cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java

Here is my code:

Server.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

class Server implements Runnable{
            static int socketCount = 0;
            Socket connectionSocket;     
            public static Vector clients=new Vector();
            public Server(Socket s){
                    try{
                            System.out.println("Client Got Connected  " );
                            connectionSocket=s;
                    }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
            }     
            public void run(){
                    try{
                            BufferedReader reader =
                                            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
                            BufferedWriter writer= 
                                            new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(connectionSocket.getOutputStream()));

                            clients.add(writer); 

                        while(true){
                            String data1 = reader.readLine().trim();
                            System.out.println("Received : "+data1);      

                            for (int i=0;i<clients.size();i++){
                               try{
                                    BufferedWriter bw= (BufferedWriter)clients.get(i);
                                    bw.write(data1);
                                    bw.write("\r\n");
                                    bw.flush();
                                }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
                            }
                        }
                    }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
        }
    private static final int CONNECTION_LIMIT = 10; 
    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Threaded Chat Server is Running  ");
    ServerSocket mysocket = new ServerSocket(5555);

    while (true) {
        Socket sock = mysocket.accept();
        Server server = new Server(sock);
        if (socketCount++ < CONNECTION_LIMIT) {
            Thread serverThread = new Thread(server);
            serverThread.start();
         } else {
            // without starting a thread and notifying only new client
            socketCount--;
            server.sayGoodbye();  
         }
    }
}

public void sayGoodbye() throws IOException 
{
    try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(connectionSocket.getOutputStream()))) 
    {
        writer.write("Sorry, a new client connections are exceeding the server limit thus it will not be accepted");
    } catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    connectionSocket.close();

}
public int getSocket() 
    {

     return socketCount; 
    }
}
```

mychat.java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class mychat implements Runnable
{
    public JTextField tx;
    public JTextArea ta;
    Server asd = new Server();
    public String login="Imed";

    BufferedWriter writer;
    BufferedReader reader;

    public mychat(String l)
    {
        login=l;        
        startclient z = new startclient();

        JFrame f=new JFrame(z.getName()+"'s Chat");
        f.setSize(400,400);        

        JPanel p1=new JPanel();
        p1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel p2=new JPanel();
        p2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());        

        tx=new JTextField();
        p1.add(tx, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JButton b1=new JButton("Send");
        p1.add(b1, BorderLayout.EAST); 

        ta=new JTextArea();
        p2.add(ta, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        p2.add(p1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        f.setContentPane(p2);



        try
        {
                 Socket socketClient= new Socket("localhost",5555);
                 writer= new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socketClient.getOutputStream()));

                 reader =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socketClient.getInputStream()));




        }

        catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}


        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev)
            {
                String s=login+" : "+tx.getText();  
                tx.setText("");
                try
                {
                    writer.write(s);
                    writer.write("\r\n");
                    writer.flush(); 
                }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
          }
        );
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        f.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent windowEvent) {
        if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(f, 
            "Are you sure you want to close this window?", "Close Window?", 
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE) == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){

            asd.getSocket() = asd.getSocket() - 1;
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
});

        f.setVisible(true);    


    }
    public void run()
    {
             try
             {
                String serverMsg=""; 
                while((serverMsg = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    System.out.println("from server: " + serverMsg);
                    ta.append(serverMsg+"\n");
                }
             }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
}
```

startclient.java

```
import java.util.*;
public class startclient
{
        static String name;
        public static void main(String [] args)
        {

                   try
                   {


                            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                            System.out.print ("Enter your name : ");
                            name = sc.nextLine();
                            mychat c=new mychat(name);   
                            Thread t1=new Thread(c);
                            t1.start();
                    }
           catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

        }
    public String getName() 
    {

     return name; 
    }
    }
```

Every time I try to compile the mychat.java, I get this error message:

```
mychat.java:13: error: constructor Server in class Server cannot be applied to given types;
    Server asd = new Server();
                 ^
  required: Socket
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
mychat.java:90: error: unexpected type
                        asd.getSocket() = asd.getSocket() - 1;
                                     ^
  required: variable
  found:    value
2 errors
```

I want to limit how many clients can join the server, which kind of works, by adding a new integer called `socketCount` at Server.java and then increasing the count every time there are new clients joining and if the number of clients is exceeding the server limit, it will reject it.

But it seems that even though I already close the client, the `socketCount` value is still not decreasing and thus a new client could not enter even though I already giving it places.

Which is why I try to fix it by decreasing the `socketCount` value at mychat.java every time I close the program, but this error happens.

How can I resolve the error?

Comment: You created the `Server` constructor to take a `Socket` as an argument (`public Server(Socket s)`), so give it one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the error log here:

```
mychat.java:13: error: constructor Server in class Server cannot be applied to given types;
    Server asd = new Server();
```

That means you have to put the Socket whenever you create the Server instance.

Your constructor here:

```
public Server(Socket s){
                    try{
                            System.out.println("Client Got Connected  " );
                            connectionSocket=s;
                    }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
            }
```

So, put the Socket to your instance and it should work fine.

Besides that, you should format your codes to be more readable. The class/methods should follow the Coding Convention. It will help you in the future.

Hope this help